Split variable stdout into lines and loop over using items from another list
I am writing an Ansible playbook designed to dynamically check available upgrades for a specified list of packages.
I am doing this by first checking the list of available packages and registering a variable:
name: Record Available Updates
command: "dnf list updates"
register: available_updates
ignore_errors: yes
args:
warn: false
when: server_role != 'n/a'

Stdout for this command is a bit messy:
TASK [foreman-patching/check-major-package-upgrades : Display all available packages] ***
ok: [dcb-zabbix.REDACTED.local] => {
    "msg": "Updating Subscription Management repositories.\nPowerTools x86_64 os                             54 kB/s | 2.6 kB     00:00    \nextras x86_64 os                                 39 kB/s | 1.8 kB     00:00    \nEPEL 8                                           46 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00    \nBaseOS x86_64 os                                 51 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00    \nNGINX Official RHEL 8                            32 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    \nHighAvailability x86_64 os                       50 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00    \nAppStream x86_64 os                              58 kB/s | 2.6 kB     00:00    \nZabbix 6.0 RH 8                                  28 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    \nMariaDB Centos 8                                 43 kB/s | 2.0 kB     00:00    \nElastic / Beats Alma 8                           30 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    \nManual NonRepo RPMs Alma 8                       34 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    \nAvailable Upgrades\ncronie.x86_64                1.5.2-8.el8.alma.1  REDACTED_Alma_8_BaseOS_x86_64_os\ncronie-anacron.x86_64        1.5.2-8.el8.alma.1  REDACTED_Alma_8_BaseOS_x86_64_os\nzabbix-agent.x86_64          6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 \nzabbix-apache-conf.noarch    6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 \nzabbix-get.x86_64            6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 \nzabbix-java-gateway.x86_64   6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 \nzabbix-selinux-policy.x86_64 6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 \nzabbix-sender.x86_64         6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 \nzabbix-server-mysql.x86_64   6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 \nzabbix-sql-scripts.noarch    6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 \nzabbix-web.noarch            6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 \nzabbix-web-deps.noarch       6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 \nzabbix-web-mysql.noarch      6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 "
}

But it becomes a lot cleaner to manage if I split by newline (\n):
TASK [foreman-patching/check-major-package-upgrades : Display all available packages] ***
ok: [dcb-zabbix.REDACTED.local] => {
    "msg": [
        "Updating Subscription Management repositories.",
        "PowerTools x86_64 os                             54 kB/s | 2.6 kB     00:00    ",
        "extras x86_64 os                                 39 kB/s | 1.8 kB     00:00    ",
        "EPEL 8                                           46 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00    ",
        "BaseOS x86_64 os                                 51 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00    ",
        "NGINX Official RHEL 8                            32 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    ",
        "HighAvailability x86_64 os                       50 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00    ",
        "AppStream x86_64 os                              58 kB/s | 2.6 kB     00:00    ",
        "Zabbix 6.0 RH 8                                  28 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    ",
        "MariaDB Centos 8                                 43 kB/s | 2.0 kB     00:00    ",
        "Elastic / Beats Alma 8                           30 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    ",
        "Manual NonRepo RPMs Alma 8                       34 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    ",
        "Available Upgrades",
        "cronie.x86_64                1.5.2-8.el8.alma.1  REDACTED_Alma_8_BaseOS_x86_64_os",
        "cronie-anacron.x86_64        1.5.2-8.el8.alma.1  REDACTED_Alma_8_BaseOS_x86_64_os",
        "zabbix-agent.x86_64          6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 ",
        "zabbix-apache-conf.noarch    6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 ",
        "zabbix-get.x86_64            6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 ",
        "zabbix-java-gateway.x86_64   6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 ",
        "zabbix-selinux-policy.x86_64 6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 ",
        "zabbix-sender.x86_64         6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 ",
        "zabbix-server-mysql.x86_64   6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 ",
        "zabbix-sql-scripts.noarch    6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 ",
        "zabbix-web.noarch            6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 ",
        "zabbix-web-deps.noarch       6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 ",
        "zabbix-web-mysql.noarch      6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 "
    ]
}

I want to be able to loop over the contents of this variable using each item in a sub-list called and return any lines that match:
services[server_role].packages

This holds data in the following structure for visibility:
services:
  zabbix:
    packages:
      - 'zabbix-server'
      - 'zabbix-agent'
      - 'httpd'
      - 'MariaDB-server'

I can loop over these without any problem e.g.:
- name: Display major packages list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ services[server_role].packages }}"

But I can't seem to get the output of the available_updates into a workable format to be able to compare/loop over.
I've tried a number of different approaches both trying to loop directly over available_updates.stdout.split('\n') in situ, and also trying to first convert it into a list, but even trying to split into the list gives me errors.
Some of the many things I've tried:
- name: Convert available_updates.stdout into a list
  set_fact:
    updates_list: "{{ available_updates | split(',') }}"

- name: Display matching available updates
  debug:
    msg: "{{ line }}"
  loop: "{{ available_updates.stdout.split('\n') }}"
  when: "{{ line.split(' ')[0] }}" in services[server_role].packages

- name: Display matching available updates
  debug:
    msg: "{{ line }}"
  loop: "{{ available_updates.stdout.split('\n') }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: line
  when: services[server_role].packages is defined and line is match(".*{{ services[server_role].packages | join('.*') }}.*")

Can anybody help me get the stdout data into something useable so I can then loop over it to look for matching items/even suggest a better approach?

Use the dnf module with list: updates (see the yum module for a better documentation of that parameter). Or even better (if info is available on your platform) use package_facts

Figured out a much simpler alternative by building the search pattern first and piping it into an extended grep:
 name: Get list of updates for specified packages
  shell: "dnf list updates | grep -Ei '{{ package_string }}'"
  register: updates_output
  vars:
    package_string: "{{ services[server_role].packages | join('|') }}"

- name: Display all available packages
  debug:
    msg: "{{ updates_output.stdout.split('\n') }}"

Giving me the output:
TASK [foreman-patching/check-major-package-upgrades : Display all available packages] ***
ok: [dcb-zabbix.REDACTED] => {
"msg": [
"zabbix-agent.x86_64 6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 ",23
"zabbix-server-mysql.x86_64 6.0.28-release1.el8 REDACTED_Alma_8_Zabbix_6_0_RH_8 "
]
}

